# Multi-tenant Azure Architecture

Tags: azure, architecture, multi-tenant, azure-front-door

I have the following scenario and am looking for tips or suggestions that I may have overlooked.

- ReactJS/C# Web API backend supporting multiple tenants.
- SQL databases are separated by client (1 database per client)
- The SQL databases are separated into 2 VNETS (USA and Canada) and cannot communicate with one another. I don't have the luxury of changing the network configuration - I need to work with what is there.
- I have a wildcard domain cert and Azure Frontdoor setup to accept any subdomain (Ex: tenant1.abc.com)

To conceptualize this, we can view the different tenants and their corresponding location map as follows:

[image]

I would like to do something similar (see below) in terms of architecture but am having a hard time getting Frontdoor to do what I want
[image]
What I am trying to achieve:

- I would like to be able to map a tenant name (found through the subdomain) to a specific backend pool (USA or Canada)
- There are about 700 tenants total and I know Frontdoor Standard has limitations

Is there a better way to do this? Would maybe having a locator service in front of the VNETs and act as a proxy?

**I'm open to all suggestions.**

Comment: Why not just set up multiple Front Door instances? Standard SKU has a limit of 100 domains/routes/origins, so you would shard into 7 instances.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. Thanks for the input.